# Waiting for xml file writing to finish in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I have written this script to write data to an xml file. It is writing correctly, but I want to wait for finish writing in xml file then I will execute another code. This means another code is depend on xml data write.

So how to wait for finish writing data in xml file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('output.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for country in root('country'):
    root.attrib['value']=data
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Above code is example code and `data` can be in more amount, so it will take time to write. some body let me know how to do that.

Comment: if you have more data then it will take time to write, but you can use `with` for writing file and it will take care of closing file and completion of process. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Comment: @Lafada i tried with `with` but same issue it is not waiting to finish writing in xml file. give another idea if u have

Comment: `tree.write` will wait till the process complete. I dont think it will execute next statement until `tree.write` complete its job.

Answer (score 1):

[Python File write() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_write.htm) states

> The method write() writes a string str to the file. There is no return
>   value. Due to buffering, the string may not actually show up in the
>   file until the flush() or close() method is called.

Thus, if you do not want to close the file after the write (so that other functions can open and read it) you can put

```
tree.flush() # does not work because no flush method in ElementTree
```

immediately after the write.

I see that the manual shows the write explicitly into the file name as opposed to a file descriptor. However, this seems to be done in interactive mode.

If the script can handle file descriptors, then the flush() or close() method on the file descriptor would be useful.

An example shown elsewhere gives an example of writing to a file using file descriptors. This would open and close the file as well as allowing the flush. The exact method is left up to you (:-)

```
text = ET.tostring(reply)
self.wfile.write(text)
```

Comment: it is givng this error `AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'flush'`

Comment: Looking at the code, perhaps if you opened the file explicitly and performed the flush on the file descriptor rather than on tree, it might work.